# Tag overhaul.. What tags should we add, modify, and adjust

Tags: discussion, tagging

I know our tag system is evolving and growing but some of us have had talks about what tags should be deprecated, some that should be added, and some that simply just dont make sense.  I was curious to know what tags some of you feel need work..  HOWEVER, **please post a single tag with your argument and others can vote on them so we can target the tags that you feel need are of more importance**:

*Example:*

[bacon](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bacon)

Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tongue venison fatback ribeye ham. Ball tip venison pastrami, sausage short ribs tri-tip pork belly bresaola drumstick. Bacon pancetta andouille ball tip tail ham. Leberkas prosciutto cow, chuck venison hamburger sirloin bacon corned beef beef chicken tail shank pastrami. Spare ribs fatback pancetta landjaeger, prosciutto andouille beef ribs bacon biltong rump ham hock ground round. Hamburger spare ribs ball tip, rump fatback ribeye jerky pork loin pancetta strip steak. Jowl rump pastrami ribeye.

Comment: ...I take it you don't really like meat.

Comment: That may be the case but if we can address the issues and discuss them as a community they will be resolved quicker and the site will become more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

[design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design)

As with [graphics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), I think this tag doesn't add anything. The tag excerpt is snarky enough as-is:

`Questions about design in general. This tag could fit just about any question on this site, try and find something more specific!`

Comment: This one has always been a pet peeve of mine, I'd equate it to having a "programming" tag on Stack Overflow. We should split it up into the more meaningful subsets of design such as [tag:website-design], [tag:gui-design], [tag:design-principles], [tag:product-design], etc

Comment: Completely agree with "design", not sure about "graphics". We talked about separating it in raster vs vector, but if you look at the question list it might have some use as a starting tag, one of those safe ones new users can add and then let others edit more specific ones.

Comment: Only reason why I would be against removing graphics is if we saw or have a question that actually focuses on someone printing a graphic and has a good question in regards to it.

Comment: This is gone (and marked as an "intrinsic" tag, so it won't be allowed back).

Comment: and the crowds cheered!

Answer (score 7):

[graphics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics)

This tag is very, very broad. Arguably, everything we discuss on this site is graphics-related. Even the tag's excerpt says it all:

`"Graphics" covers an immense variation: In general, any visual representation of a concept can be referred to as a "graphic". Visual representations may include - but are not limited to - photographs, drawings, charts, typography, numbers.`

Comment: Agreed with this and [tag:design]. As you pointed out in chat, it was proposed early on that [graphic-design should be blacklisted](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/135/8708). I guess it multiplied rather than accept defeat (like a hydra?)

Answer (score 7):

[adobe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe)

This tends to get pinned on any adobe-* question. I don't see any utility in adding it to a question that already has [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop), [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator), etc.

I don't think it should be completely obliterated; I think there are valid use cases for it. [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25123/8708) comes to mind, or any question strictly pertaining to Adobe Systems Incorporated and not a specific software.

There are currently 102 questions tagged under [adobe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe), so it wouldn't be too difficult to clean this up manually. The solution I propose is to remove it from any question tagged [adobe-*] (and retag if appropriate). I keep this one on my list of favorite tags to make it easier to spot.

Comment: I think with a group effort of the members of this Stack if you created a meta post and asked for people to take 5 questions a day tagged [tag:adobe] and re-tag the question with the removal of Adobe in a week or two the tag would be eliminated.

Comment: @Gramps I'm in.

Comment: 100% for this! Let the re-tagging begin.

Comment: there's only 31 left, and all of them are either appropriately tagged, or they are closed/on hold and I didn't want to edit them because of that.

Answer (score 4):

[illustration](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustration) gets overused on a lot of questions that are actually about [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator). There's a lot of questions that rightfully use the tag, though, so I'm not proposing to kill it or anything. It just needs... weeding.

Answer (score 3):

I think its redundant to have [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) and [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) but I am more towards the removal of tag [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) because almost any question non-software related can be labeled as feedback..