# Design is dead. Long live design!

Tags: discussion, tags

As a follow-up to [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1167/8708) last month, the [design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag has been killed (the official term is [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)):

> This is gone (and marked as an "intrinsic" tag, so it won't be allowed back). –  [Shog9♦](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/tag-overhaul-what-tags-should-we-add-modify-and-adjust/1168#comment3509_1167)

It will be significantly more useful to encourage *specific* types of design tags instead. Since the tag browser can be difficult to navigate if you don't know what's out there, which existing specific design tags do we have (or perhaps which ones should be created)?

Comment: You need to change your avatar to Trogdor right meow!

Comment: @Ryan as you wish!

Comment: Splendid! It always was top tag on the daft-o-meter.

Comment: Good.. **speedy** response to that discussion :)

Comment: @Scott my typical turnaround time is 4-6 weeks, if you need moderation quicker there is an additional fee (industry standard)

Comment: Damn. Just like all blood-sucking moderators!

Comment: Just a note.... the original "this discussion" link  was tied to a meta question from 2011.... hence my original comment. :) Sneaky moderators updated the link to make me look foolish. **As if** I needed their help for that! The nerve.

Comment: Nice! it won't be missed.

Answer (score 4):

### Types of Design

- [website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)
- [print-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-design)
- [gui-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design)
- [template-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template-design)
- [responsive-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design)
- [chart-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chart-design)
- [character-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-design)
- [font-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-design)
- [presentation-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation-design)
- [product-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-design)
- [information-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-design)

### About Design

- [design-principles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-principles)
- [designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designers)
- [design-process](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-process)
- [history](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)

Comment: I've grabbed the easy ones by searching the tags for "design", but if any others should be added to either of the lists don't hesitate!